# python/django- number comparison (>) does not work

Tags: python, django

This is really weird. I have a django program and I am calling this py file from views. The file will read from an excel and find the correct number index for a given number(target).

It keeps telling me "Target Number out of Range" which it should not, so I print out the numbers.

```
for target in target_list:
    print target, df[pin_num][end], df[pin_num][0]
    if target > df[pin_num][end] or target < df[pin_num][0]:
        print target, df[pin_num][end], df[pin_num][0]
        print target > df[pin_num][end]
        print target < df[pin_num][0]
        return "Target Number out of Range"
```

The Console(using pycharm) show:

> 23925.85 24472.9 23876.0
>
> 23925.85 24472.9 23876.0
>
> True
>
> False
>
> Target Number out of Range

How could this ever happen? 23925.85 is obviously smaller than 24472.9 ... And I have print out everything I need to compare.

Comment: Are you sure they're all numbers? Maybe some of those are actually strings.

Comment: @Rawing Even strings would not return the above result. `'24...'` is lexicographic-ally greater than `'23...'` except there is a leading space in the first string

Comment: @pwnsauce The number of characters does not matter

Comment: The point Rawing was making was that if `target` is a string but the contents of `df` are floats, then (assuming this is Python 2) target would be treated as greater.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah yes, that is most likely the case then

Comment: @Rawing you are correct... One of them is str and the others are float.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman hinted, if you were using Python 3, comparison between a string and a float would give `TypeError: unorderable types`.

Answer (score 0):

So as @Rawing mentioned in comments, I added

`print type(target), type(df[pin_num][end]), type(df[pin_num][0])`

and it showed target is a string.

so I added :

```
    target=float(target)
```

This solve my problem.